# When does $ |{x}|^\alpha\sin{\frac1{x}} $ have continuous derivative at zero?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let

$$f(x) :=\begin{cases} |{x}|^\alpha\sin{\frac1{x}},&x\ne0\\0,&\text{otherwsie}\end{cases}$$

I've come up with that the derivative at zero is:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|{x}|^\alpha\sin{\frac1{x}}}{x} = 0$$ for $\alpha\ge2$.

But how do I get the derivative function to see when it's equal to its limit?

$$\lim_{x\to y}\frac{|{x}|^\alpha\sin{\frac1{x}}-|{y}|^\alpha\sin{\frac1{y}}}{x-y} = \text{the function}$$

Or how do I compute $$\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to y}\frac{|{x}|^\alpha\sin{\frac1{x}}-|{y}|^\alpha\sin{\frac1{y}}}{x-y} = \text{desired limit to compare with }0$$

Comment: for $\alpha>1$ is also true that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|x|^\alpha}x\sin(1/x)=0$

Comment: To have a derivative defined you need to have a value defined for $x=0$; presumably you mean to define the value of $f(x)=\left|x\right|^\alpha\sin\frac1x$ at $x=0$ to be $0$ for $\alpha\gt 0$ (as that's the continuous extension), but it wouldn't hurt to mention that explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function doesnt have a simple way to define it derivative directly from the definition of derivative at a point because it is a composition of functions. In this case it is better to use the chain and the product rule, that show that

$$[(f\circ g)(x)\cdot h(x)]'=[(f\circ g)(x)]'\cdot h(x)+(f\circ g)(x)\cdot h'(x)\\=(f'\circ g)(x)g'(x)h(x)+(f\circ g)(x)h'(x)$$

whenever the functions involved are differentiable at the point $x$. In your case, for $x\neq 0$, we have that

$$f'(x)=[|x|^\alpha\sin(1/x)]'=[|x|^\alpha]'\sin(1/x)+|x|^\alpha[\sin(1/x)]'\\=\alpha|x|^{\alpha-1}\operatorname{sign}(x)\sin(1/x)+|x|^\alpha\cos(1/x)\cdot\frac{-1}{x^2}\\=|x|^{\alpha-2}(\alpha x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x))$$

where $\operatorname{sign}$ is the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). From here you only need to see for what values of $\alpha$ it holds that

$$\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=0$$

Comment: I see. And that should be for $a>2$, shouldn't?

Comment: @Adam yes, for $\alpha >2$

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\frac{|x|^{\alpha}|\sin(\frac{1}{x})|}{|x|}\le |x|^{\alpha-1}$$
it must be $$\alpha>1$$ so $$|x|^{\alpha-1}$$ tends to zero for $x$ tends to zero

Comment: But what is that on the left? I have no idea how the derivative function of the function in the title looks like.

Comment: Oh either I have or my first derivative is wrong.